# ActiveAdmin forms (new/edit) belongs_to association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I use Active Admin gem for Ruby on Rails.
I have modules Team and Coach, which have a has_many and belongs_to relationship.

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :coach
end

class Coach < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teams
end
```

I figured out how to display first name and last name on index and show page (i did it like that:)

```
  index do
    column :name
    column "Coach" do |team|
      team.coach.firstname + " " + team.coach.lastname
    end  
     default_actions
  end
```

What i want is how to display first name and last name of coach in Team form (new and edit page) in dropdown menu?
Please help me with this.

Answer (score 10):

Can you try this

```
f.input :coach_name, :as => :select, :collection => Coach.all.map {|u| [u.firstname, u.id]}, :include_blank => false
```

Comment: this is the correct answer, however, i would recommend calling Coach.pluck(:firstname, :id) instead which is much more efficient and avoids unnecessary database calls.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. The edit page shows object instances in the select menu such as,

```
#<Coach:0x00eff180c85c8>
```

To solve it and access each instance's fields use this,

```
form do |f| 
  f.inputs "Coaches" do
    f.input :name
    f.input :coach, member_label: Proc.new { |c| "#{c.firstname} #{c.lastname}"
  end
  f.actions
end
```

ActiveAdmin uses Formtastic and its [documentation](http://rdoc.info/github/justinfrench/formtastic/Formtastic/Inputs/RadioInput) has more examples.

This stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17229692/1366534) helped me get this solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
f.input :coach_name, :as => :select, :collection => Coach.all.map {|u| [u.firstname.to_s, u.id]}
```