# belongs_to association and formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic, belongs-to

I have a model Product which has a belongs_to association with another model Type. In the product's form, I'm using formtastic to display a select tag with all the types available in the database, like this:

```
<%= f.input :type %>
```

The select is showing up OK, but each option of it is an object instance of the Type model as a string, for example:

```
#<Type:0x00eff180c85c8>
```

Instead of that, I'd like to display the 'title' attribute of it, like:

```
Electronic
Domestic
...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `member_label` option, it sounds like what you want to do:

```
<%= f.input :type, :member_label => :title %>
```

The [documentation](http://rdoc.info/github/justinfrench/formtastic/Formtastic/Inputs/RadioInput) has more examples.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add this in your model

```
  def name
    return self.title
  end
```